# How to connect to local database through webpage that is not local using php

Tags: php, sql-server, client-side

My situation...

I have a webpage in PHP language + MySQL and the server is located outside of LAN.

What I need is to get result of database query (MS SQL) that is located inside my domain.
This local server with database is not opened to extranet that's why web service on client side is probably not an option.

What are my other options?
I was thinking to use javascript or activX.
The problem is that javascript expose database password as it can be viewed as clear text and activeX is only for IE.

What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to any server with the client, restricted to local/network firewalls and routing tables.

The server on the other side has the same restrictions (firewall, network routing) +
a few security tweaks:

- user table might only accept specific hosts
- `bind-address` options (in newer versions) limit access for ip/interface

  - `0.0.0.0` = all are allowed
- in older versions of the mysqld this option is called `skip-networking` to allow tcp connections
- by default mysqld listens only locally or through unix socket

The server being not exposed to the WAN, you'd either change this or use VPN to connect.